# Is a guardian friend or foe on minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So in Minecraft found a Guardian. I'm not sure if it's hostile or not. It really scared me I'm ashamed to admit it. But anyway in survival will this attack me or not?

Comment: You just had to type "guardian minecraft" on google, and the first link was containing your answer, I don't think this question has any use.

Comment: I really have to pay attention to the wiki more. New mobs? AWESOME!

Comment: Although this is technically a valid question, the downvotes are to the fact that this showes pour research effort.

Answer (score 9):

[Guardian Minecraft Wiki entry](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Guardian), first line, first sentence

> The Guardian is an underwater **hostile mob**

As for whether it'll attack you, it depends on where you are. If you're on land it will quickly move towards the nearest water source, at which point they swim away. So as long you're not in between it and a water source, you should be fine.

Comment: Sudoku beat me to it :P

Answer (score 2):

they are a foe, here is a image:
[image: zap!]
attacks:laser(zap!), spikes(prickle!)

```
/summon guardian ~ ~ ~ elder:/summon guardian ~ ~ ~ {Elder:1}
```

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the situation, when naturally spawned mostly foe. you can summon a completly friendly guardian with command blocks. you can also spawn a completly evil guardian that floats in air, always follows you, can kill you instantly in survival or even creative mode, unlimited range, unlimited sight(and can see through any block), can shoot through any block and has unlimited HP. yea you do not want to spawn that. you can even make one that acts like an ender dragon underwater. yep.

Answer (score 0):

Guardians don't like you (or squids)! They will shoot lasers at you if you are in survival and will kill you easily. I recommend you to be careful with them. Extra info: Guardians spawn in Ocean monuments and the Elder guardian deals more damage and will give you mining fatigue!